# google cloud aspnetcore default builder yaml missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Starting Friday afternoon last week, I'm suddenly unable to deploy to GCP for my project and I receive the following error:

```
...
Building and pushing image for service [myService]
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.s
storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x045FD130>]: HttpError accessing
//www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/runtime-builders/o/gs%3A%2F%2Fruntime-b
%2Faspnetcore-default-builder-20170524113403.yaml?alt=media>: response: <
s': '404', 'content-length': '9', 'expires': 'Mon, 05 Jun 2017 14:33:42 G
ary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'x-guploader-uploadid
B2UpOw2hMicKUV6j5FRap9x4UKxxZsb04j9JxWA_kc27S_AIPf0QZQ40H6OZgZcLJxCnnx5m4
8x3JV3p9kvZZy-A', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Mon, 05
17 14:33:42 GMT', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="38,37,36,35"',
t-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <Not Found>. Please retry.
```

I tried again this morning and even updated my gcloud components to version 157.  I continue to see this error.

Item of note, the 20170524113403 value in that YAML filename is, I think, a match to the first successful deploy to .NET App Flex for my project.  I had since deleted that version using the Google Cloud Explorer with a more recent version 'published' early Friday morning.  My publish worked Friday morning, now it doesn't.  I don't see any logs that help me understand why that file is even needed and an Agent Ransack search on my entire drive doesn't reveal where that filename is coming from to try and point it to a more recent version.

I'm doing this through both Google Cloud Tools integrated into my Visual Studio 2017 (Publish to Google Cloud...) as well as running the command lines:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Release
copy app.yaml -> destination location
gcloud beta app deploy .\app.yaml in destination location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was "fixed" by Google or not, but 4 days later, the problem went away.  On some additional information, I was able to locate the logs on my machine during the publish phase and saw something interesting.

**When Working:**

```
2017-05-25 09:36:48,821 DEBUG    root            Calculated builder definition using legacy version [gs://runtime-builders/aspnetcore-default-builder-20170524113403.yaml]
```

**Later when it stopped working:**

```
 2017-06-02 15:25:15,312 DEBUG    root            Resolved runtime [aspnetcore] as build configuration [gs://runtime-builders/gs://runtime-builders/aspnetcore-default-builder-20170524113403.yaml]
```

What I noticed was the duplicated "gs://runtime-builders/gs//runtime-builders..."

which disappeared this morning... no, I didn't change a thing besides waiting until today.

```
2017-06-07 08:11:37,042 INFO     root            Using runtime builder [gs://runtime-builders/aspnetcore-default-builder-20170524113403.yaml]
```

You'll see that double "gs://runtime-builders/gs://runtime-builders/" is GONE.